# Linker command failed, cannot find library in existing project

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I'm trying to fix an existing project. To make some bugfixes. When I first opened the project, the libraries where missing so I've linked them again. Because the project was on a private Git.

When all libraries were linked again I received this error. I already tried to delete my DirevedData, but there was no change.

Is there anybody who understands this error and who's willing to help me with it?

Thanks!

[image]

I've changed the folders of my project so the warnings of "Directory not found are OK" But now I received following error.

[image]

Comment: What's to understand?  The linker cannot find `/Users/simonsalomos/blah/blah`.  Do those directories exist?

Comment: are all these libraries integrated through cocoa pods?

Comment: Sorry. I've added those again in the righ folder but now I received another error. http://imgur.com/LckxfuQ